# Making the sound for a Flash game

Tags: flash, audio

Hu guys, I'm developing a Flash game, and I'm interested in knowing what would be the process of making sounds.

I want to make my own sounds, if possible, and not to download some premade standard (and possibly lawsuitable if they are not "totally free") sounds from the web.

So.. I've read that a synthesizer could be useful.. but, I really dont know.

Thx!

Comment: What kind of sounds are you looking to make?

Comment: I'd suggest talking to a sound engineer

Comment: The kind of sounds I want to make are like shots, explosions, an enviroment music.. and not much more than that, maybe some button fx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ready-made sounds are the way to go. Google for royalty free loops, sound effects etc.

If you are too curious to get your hands dirty, try some free vst plugins from kvr-audio etc. along with Reaper (non-expiring savable free trial)

search in my bookmarks - delicious.com/raguanu I've saved zillions resources in these lines.

Comment: Yep, I thought that :)

Im going to check that stuff you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Andre Michelle's lab if your interested in creating real time sounds. He is probably the leading authority when it comes to audio and Flash and has made lots of Flash synths (with source code available).
http://lab.andre-michelle.com/tag/audio/

Comment: Interesting work indeed, but, for my game I'll use some premade sounds, like explosions, gunshots, etc.. I dont know if that kind of sounds would apply...

Comment: @Artemix yeah I guess it would only be suited to 8 bit style sounds or midi style music. Also take a look at http://www.freesound.org/ for free sound files

Comment: Yeah, I thought that.... anw, I think I may use that ideas to alter some of my premade sounds I guess.

Comment: Wait, can I use those sounds and make profit of it?, I saw that it uses CC license, but... dont know that much about licenses :p

Comment: Yeah I am no expert either haha. It seems as long as you only sample/ mashup then you are able to use is commercially - as long as you attribute whoever made it. Well thats my take on it anyway http://www.freesound.org/legal.php

Answer (score 0):

Audio engineering is as big a domain as (and possibly even bigger than) programming. If you want to do more than record something using a single microphone, you'll have to make a huge investment in time, and possibly money. I'd suggest using free sounds, or if there's money at stake, hiring someone.

There's no shame in not creating 100% of the game and content from scratch -- not everyone is an artist, programmer, music composer, game designer, audio engineer, web designer, etc.

Comment: I see, thx for your answer.

I know that there is no shame in using some premade sounds.. but I just wanted to know how difficult would be to do it myself from scratch. I dont have a problem to invest some money buying some necesary products, like a good quality mic, a digital recorder, etc.

Comment: To be honest, it's more of a time investment than a money investment, unless you end up building yourself a recording studio (I did... oops). The more time you put in learning and practicing, the better your results will be. You'll start off making terrible, cheesy sounds, but you'll get better with practice. I guess there's really no reason not to try your hand at it... you'll know after a few hours whether audio is your "thing" or not.

Answer (score 0):

When I made [my flash game](http://bob.tmont.com/SCL.html), I took inspiration from [this guy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwxN8sCIOOE) and recorded myself with a microphone - it's a little low-budget, but it is fun. ;)  Well, I did that for the sound effects; my [brother](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242489/tmont) has a digital recorder and wrote and recorded the music.

Then I used [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) to edit the clips and clean them up and convert them to .mp3s.

Comment: Pretty triangle game :)

I'll consider that option too, thx.